# Hibernate: Unable to Apply Constrains on DDL

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, struts

I'm using Struts/Springs/Hibernate with Tomcat 7.0, and I'm getting an issue with hibernate's mapping when attempting to start-up the server.

The console will print:

```
Mapping class: path.vo.ObjectVO -> TABLE_NAME
```

for each item in the HibernateSessionFactory.xml file and its associated VO object found in the hibernate folder.  It will successfully iterate through the ENTIRE list.

However, once it appears to be successful, it chokes up on a couple objects, giving this error:

```
WARN: Unable to apply constraints on DDL for path.vo.ObjectVO
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: path.vo.ObjectVO
```

The odd thing is that the server used to run fine.  I haven't changed any hibernate configuration files, VO objects, or the database schema itself since the time when it ran successfully.  My research has only led people fixing issues with their configuration files which haven't worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated.  Here are some of the files I'm using.

**HibernateSessionFactory.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate/ClassA.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/ClassB.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

**ClassA.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="path.to.ClassAVO" table="CLASSA">
    <id name ="Id" type="int">
        <column name="ID"/>
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="somecolumn" type="string">
        <column name="Somecolumn" length="24" not-null="true" />
    </property>
 ...
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Do you map ObjectVO to some table? VO is not supposed to be persistent

Comment: @HenryLeu i thought this line does that: <class name="path.to.ClassAVO" table="CLASSA">

Answer (score 0):

1. Two POs maping to the same table is prohibited in Hibernate.
2. VO is supposed to be wraping data and transfered across layers instead of being persisted.
3. I suggest you 'd better follow good practice of layering design which the open surce community are familiar with and can help you.

See [Working with objects in hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html)